# Jenkins - Fail a job if condition is not met

Tags: jenkins, conditional-statements

In the Jenkins job which tests some values, I have something like this:

```
stage('Check value'){
    if value == 5:
        //return failure of a job
}

stage('Send results'){
    ....
}
```

In one stage those values are being checked, if value == 5 a job should return failure. I've tried with exit 1 and with return -1 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you gracefully return from a stage the next stage will always run. So one way to get around this is to conditionally run all other `Stages`. Another solution is to simply generate an error. Refer to the following pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build_1') {
            steps {
                echo "Running!!!"
                script {
                    def value = 5
                    if(value == 5)  {
                         currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                         error("Abort the build.")
                         // throw new Exception("ERRRRORRRRRR") -> Or you can throw an error.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build_2') {
            steps {
                echo "Running!!! 22222"
            }
        }
    }
}
```